# How can I rename a window using my keyboard?

Tags: google-chrome

There appears to be no way to access the Chrome window menu or to rename the current window without using a mouse. How can I rename the current window using my keyboard?

Oddly, Chrome has at least four different right-click (context) menus based on where you right-click. You can access the context menu of the currently active Chrome element with the menu key on your keyboard. Is there a way to activate the title bar with the keyboard?

[image]

Comment: On my box (latest Win11 latest Chrome) the "w" is underlined https://i.imgur.com/1mfcAe1.png so you can press Alt+Space and then W, in your case you probably should press Alt+Space and then use the down arrow and Enter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press `Alt + e` then `l` `w` *(while keep Alt down)* to open chrome three-dot menu and choose option `Name window`  (underline character on label item `More tools` > `Name window`), it depends on the operating system the keyboard shortcut or label name of chrome three-dot menu may change.

*Keep hold `Alt` down while open menu to see which character was underline*

You could move selection by key `up` or `down` or open or close sub menu by press `left` or `right` and choose by `enter`.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> opens the window menu. Then press <kbd>w</kbd> to rename the window.

[image]